# apache pig ordering after grouping

Tags: apache-pig

I have a list as below.

```
from    to  duration 
5       10  1
10      30  15
10      30  25
5       10  10
10      40  15
5       20  5
```

I need to find the from-to pairs which are the most occuring like below.

```
from    to  count 
10      30      2
5       10      2
```

I have grouped them by 'from, to' and I can find the count like below.

```
10  30  2
10  40  1
5   20  1
5   10  2
```

How to extract only the maximum pair count.

```
a = load 'x' using PigStorage;
b = group a by (from, to);
c = foreach b {
d = COUNT(c);
generate group, d;};
e = group d all;
f = foreach e {
g = order e by d;
h = limit g 1;
generate group, h; };
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try and let me know if this work for you.

**UPDATE:**
If you don't have `RANK` operator, download `piggbank.jar` and set it in your classpath and try the below approach.
**input.txt**

```
5       10      1
10      30      15
10      30      25
5       10      10
10      40      15
5       20      5
```

**PigScript:** **Pig version<11**

```
    REGISTER /tmp/piggybank.jar;

    DEFINE MyOver org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.Over('myrank:int');
    DEFINE MyStitch org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.Stitch;

    A = LOAD 'input.txt' AS (from,to,duration);
    B = GROUP A BY (from,to);
    C = FOREACH B{
                    mycount = COUNT($1);
                    GENERATE group, mycount AS cnt;
                 }
    D = GROUP C ALL;
    E = FOREACH D  {
                      mysort = ORDER C BY cnt DESC;
                      GENERATE FLATTEN(MyStitch(mysort,MyOver(mysort,'dense_rank',0,1,1)));
                   };
    F = FILTER E BY stitched::myrank==1;
    G = FOREACH F GENERATE FLATTEN(stitched::group),stitched::cnt;
    DUMP G;
```

**Output:**

```
(5,10,2)
(10,30,2)
```

**PigScript:** **Pigversion >=11 support Rank operator**

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' AS (from,to,duration);
B = GROUP A BY (from,to);
C = FOREACH B{
                mycount = COUNT($1);
                GENERATE group, mycount AS cnt;
             }
D = RANK C BY cnt DESC;
E = FILTER D BY rank_C==1;
F = FOREACH E GENERATE FLATTEN(group),cnt;
DUMP F;
```

**Output:**

```
(5,10,2)
(10,30,2)
```

Comment: This did not work as the pig version did not have support for rank.

Answer (score 0):

The above will work for sure. I thought of writing the logic like this.
 But the code is lengthy here.

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' AS (from,to,duration);
B = GROUP A BY (from,to);
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(group) AS(from,to),COUNT(A.from) as count;
D = ORDER C BY count DESC;
E = LIMIT D 1;
F = JOIN C by count,E BY $2;
G = FOREACH F GENERATE $0,$1,$2;
```

Pls check this if you think it is useful